Duplicate Issue
I'm not sure why this question was closed as a duplicate. 
Link
The closed question seems more general, and about best practices for having ciphers reviewed while the "duplicated" question is more focused on publication. 
I might be picking nits though, and the linked question's answers could potentially be seen as opinion based. 
Thoughts? 

First thought: in case you're unaware of it, you can always vote to reopen if you think that makes sense and if you have the according reputation. This works like close-voting, just the other way around. And if you happen to lack the reputation, you can leave a comment so other users can become aware of potential objections and maybe also flag for moderator attention too so we get a heads-up and one of us can take a look at things.
Second thought: the "on hold" question shows several opinion-based answers too… but that might just be me looking at the downvoted answers too much.
Reopened
Anyway, since the question was put on-hold with only 3 votes (one by me), I'll reopen the Q&A for the benefit of the doubt. Yet, that doesn't mean users won't decide to close-vote it as a dupe again if they feel to do so… I (logically) have no influence on that.

I agree that it seems to be asking for primarily opinion based answers, but if we err on the side of logic I don't believe this is a duplicate.  Just my two-cents.

Note that only 47 users (as of now) can vote to re-open / close, floorcat not being one of them ;)

@SEJPM Yeah, that's what you get from all those high-reputation users. ;) Added edit to cover that “issue”. Thanks for pointing me to it.
